# MeteorJS - variable not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to meteor. I just created a Hello world project using meteor. My project structure is very simple at the moment.

> - root folder
>
>   - abc.css
>   - abc.html
>   - abc.js

In abc.js I just tried declaring a variable like this:

```
var lists = new Meteor.Collection("Lists");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
  return "My List.";
  };

  Template.hello.events({
   'click input' : function () {
   if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
      console.log("You pressed the button");
   }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
  });
}
```

But when i run this, I am getting the following error in browser console:

> [18:17:32.895] ReferenceError: lists is not defined

I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Meteor variables are scoped to a file. So if you define lists with the `var` keyword you can't access `lists` outside abc.js

To get passed this just remove the `var` so its just:

```
lists = new Meteor.Collection("Lists");
```

Then you can access it in the other files as well as your console.